# How can i submit form from android?

Tags: android, forms, email, post, submit

I am submitting form using html and now i have to create a form in android that will send message from textbox same as the website.

I don't want to use webview.

here is my html code:

```
<form action="http://example.com/form/" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Type your Message"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: refer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html

Comment: You should use a GridLayout with TextView, EditText, ..

Comment: So you know already how to post data from a textview or a string to a http server? Whith which part of the whole do you have problems with?

Comment: how to post data from a textview or a string to a http server for the above form?